# How to get altitude value using android?

Tags: android, location

I used following code, i am getting latitude and longitude value are correct but altitude value is 0. please help me

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000,
            0, (LocationListener) this);

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double lat_chn = (double) (location.getLatitude());
    double lng_chn = (double) (location.getLongitude());
    Log.d("Update Latitude= ", location.getLatitude() + "");
    Log.d("Update Longitude= ", location.getLongitude() + "");
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);

    String Text ="Latitude="+location.getAltitude()+
        "\nLongitude ="+location.hasAltitude()+"\nAltitude="+getAltitude(lat_chn,lng_chn);
}
```

Comment: ARe you sure that your device has an altitude sensor?

Comment: How to check altitude sensor in my device?

Answer (score 6):

Can you check with [sensor manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) as well because sensor managers are meant for that; IT has  getAltitude(float p0, float p) funcation that Computes the Altitude in meters from the atmospheric pressure and the pressure at sea level.

Hope it helps.

At code level you can do something like given below....

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor sensor;
    private float altitude = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (sensor != null) 
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float presure = event.values[0];
        altitude = SensorManager.getAltitude(SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE, presure);

        System.out.println("altitude => " + altitude);
    }
}
```